# Running a macro on multiple Excel files

Tags: windows, excel, vba, powershell

I'm sure this question was asked, but I can't find a solution that works for my situation. I have a text file that contains macro instructions to enter the time date in every record that is entered. I have been pasting the code in an excel file via the VB "view code" view and saving it as the file name that I want.

The problem is that it takes forever to do this on the hundreds of files I have to modify. Is there any way to automate this?

I have tried to record a macro where I paste the code and save the file, but it will save the file name of the original file that I recorded the macro on. Is there any way to edit the macro to save the file in the current directory with the current file name?

I record a macro,
I paste this code into a sheet:

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '   Code goes in the Worksheet specific module
    Dim rng As Range
        '   Set Target Range, i.e. Range("A1, B2, C3"), or Range("A1:B3")
        Set rng = Target.Parent.Range("A:A")
             '   Only look at single cell changes
            If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            '   Only look at that range
            If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            '   Action if Condition(s) are met (do your thing here...)
            With Target
                .Offset(, 1) = Date
                .Offset(, 2) = Time
            End With
End Sub`

Then I stop the macro. This is the result:

`Sub save()
 save Macro
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ChDir "P:\Inventory\templates\NB (D) Kelso 011"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "P:\Inventory\templates\NB (D) Kelso 011\D101.xlsm", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub`

Comment: If you just need the macro available for any workbook you open, save the workbook containing your macro as an Excel add-in (.xlam) at the default location.  Then go to Developer -> Add-ins and check the box to enable it. If you want to modify the macro itself to open multiple files, you'd probably want to edit your question to include the code.

Comment: I was unable to use your guidance, xlam is apparently unsupported in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently on work-PC with old 2003 Excel and when I open Macros, I have there the list of macros and "Use macros from all opened files" or "use only from this file" switch. So just make one file with macro with your code and then open other files and call macros from another file, Excel can handle this!
For newer versions I cannot try, but I am sure this useful thing can't be killed...?